# Laravel Eloquent: Retrieve only pivots values from model

Tags: laravel

I have two tables: `users` and `questions`, boolean answers are stored in an `answers` pivot table.

What function should I use/write in my `User` model to get only a list of `question_id` with `answer` from pivot table ?

```
[
  [1, true],
  [4, false],
  [7, false],
  [8, true]
]
```

```
/**
 * Get the questions for the user.
 */
public function questions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class, 'answers')->withPivot('answer');
}
```

Comment: Just write a hasMany relationship with the answer model.

Comment: Actually, I find an answer by eager loading `questions` with `id` only: `User::with('questions:id')` giving a cleaner result.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the `->withPivot` you will receive your pivot data in the `pivot` attribute of the questions model. So you can simply loop over all questions and map them to the desired format:

```php
/**
 * Returns all [question_id, answer] combinations for this user
 * @return array
 */
public function answers() : array 
{
    return $this->questions
                ->map(fn (Question $q) => [$q->id, $q->pivot->answer])
                ->toArray();
}
```

Make sure to properly [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the questions in your controller for best performance.